# Ext.Ajax Cross-Domain post request

Tags: ajax, post, extjs, request, cross-domain

I'm testing ExtJS v.5.1.0.107 and I my goal is that to perform a post ajax request on a different server. I've found some similar discussions but nothing seems to work for my scenario.
Here's request code:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                      url: 'http://192.168.1.60/test.php',
                                      method: 'POST',
                                      cors: true,
                                      useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
                                      params : {
                                          myPar1 : myPar1Value  
                                      },
                                      success: function () {
                                        alert('success');
                                      },
                                      failure: function () {
                                        alert('failure');
                                      }
                                    });
```

Here's error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.60/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.50:22800' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there something wrong?
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your files are reachable from the server...

If the server is well configured, try add a response header for

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This command will allow cross-domain through Ajax operations. Then, the requested file (test.php for instance on the targeted server) should contain in the first lines :

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Then, you should change parameter for Apache server hosting test.php file. In the .htacess file :

```
header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://192.168.1.60/"
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: It helped! Php header was missing! Thanks alot for your willingness!

Comment: @ExDev if this answered you're question, you should accept it as the answer.  Regards...